# MariaDB regex working in online regex testers does not work in SELECT WHERE REGEXP

Tags: regex, search, mariadb

I'm having a problem a dataset I have been given in bad format E.G `fullName` column and no breakdown of names I'm wanting to search where any of the names start with a given letter E.G `'J'`

So this is my Statement but I just get complaints about unexpected `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * FROM `Officers` WHERE `fullName` REGEXP '.*\sJ.*';
```

Is there any way to do this in MariaDB, unfortunately, the names are not of a fixed word count some are only 2 names others are 6 names long so 4 middle names.

Comment: Try `REGEXP '\\bJ'`

Comment: `*\sJ*` is not a regular expression, it's a globbing pattern at best. You meant to use `.*` instead of a single asterisk. `.` matches any character, `*` means zero or more times. As for the `\s`, you /might/ need to escape the backslash, making the whole expression `.*\\s.*J`; but you probably want to go with Wiktors suggestion...

Comment: it did have dot's before the stars I just miswrote it when I typed it into SO, could I ask what does \\b do I can see what its end result is but what is it's definition never seen it before?

Comment: Actually, I am a bit puzzled: if only the first word must start with `J`, there must be a non-regex way to achieve what you want. `\\b` will match a word boundary, and might match `J` that is at the beginning of a second, third, etc. names. Try something like `WHERE LEFT(TRIM(col), 1) == "J"`

Comment: first word with starting with `J` is easy `WHERE fullName LIKE 'J%'` or `WHERE SUBSTRING(fullName, 0, 1) = "J'` but the word boundary was the difficult bit but thanks, I have learnt about `\b` in regex now :) if you could make it an answer I will mark is as correct :)

Comment: @MartinBarker Good, I added some explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP '\\bJ'
        ^^^
```

Here, the `\b` is a word boundary that will force a match only when `J` is not preceded with a letter, digit or `_`.

The `\` is doubled because the regex engine expects a literal `\`, and two backslashes are required.

Comment: Notice, that in PHP you must additionally escape slashes, so something like `$db->execute( "SELECT * FROM \`Officers\` WHERE \`fullName\` REGEXP '\\\\bJ' " );` will works.

Comment: See also https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php if you need safe using strings in regexp queries: `$q='Unsafe(*abc'; $db->execute( "SELECT * FROM \`Officers\` WHERE \`fullName\` REGEXP '\\\\b" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, preg_quote($q)) . " ' " );`

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Officers` WHERE `fullName` REGEXP '[[:<:]]J'
```

See docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html